# UITextfield delegate not getting fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfielddelegate

I have a series of text fields in cells of a `UITableView`. I have implemented a collapsible table view successfully. But somehow the textfield delegate like `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing` is not getting called. I have posted the code below.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *myCell;

    if ([indexPath section]==1 && arrBlockFriendsName.count>0)
    {
        static NSString *identifier=@"BlockCell";
        BlockUsersTableViewCell *cell=(BlockUsersTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"BlockUsersTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.imgBlockFriend.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[arrBlockFriendsImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.imgBlockIcon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user_lock_icon1.png"];
        cell.lblBlockFriendName.text=[arrBlockFriendsName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblBlockFriendPlace.text=[arrBlockFriendsPlace objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        myCell=cell;
    }

    if ([indexPath section]==3)
    {
        AgeSliderTableCell *cell=(AgeSliderTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AgeCell"];
        //cell.delegate=self;

        if (cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"AgeSliderTableCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        [cell.labelSlider setUpperValue:ageUpperValue];
        [cell.labelSlider setMinimumValue:18];
        [cell.labelSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSliderLabels:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        myCell=cell;
    }

    if ([indexPath section]==4 && arrLocationLabel.count>0)
    {
        static NSString *identifierLocation=@"LocationCell";

        LocationTableViewCell *cell=nil;

        if (indexPath.row ==3)
        {
            cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierLocation];

            cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"LocationTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:1];


            [cell.btnSave addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }

        if( indexPath.row==0 || indexPath.row==1 || indexPath.row==2)
        {
            cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierLocation];

            cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"LocationTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

            cell.lblLocationDetails.text=[arrLocationLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.txtLocationDetails.delegate=self;

        }
               myCell=cell;
    }
    myCell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return myCell;
}
```

Any ideas what could be missing?

Comment: did u set the delegate for textfield....like `txtfield.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems like you are only setting the delegate for the textfield called `cell.txtLocationDetails` but **not** for `cell.lblBlockFriendName` or `cell.lblBlockFriendPlace`. You would want to do the same for them as you did for `cell.txtLocationDetails`.

Comment: I have used a label and a text field.I have also declared UItextfield delegate.The label s working fine.But the textfield delegate is not getting called

Comment: For any textfields that you want to conform to the delegate protocol, you must set the delegate for each textfield. For example if you want to implement delegate methods such as `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing` you have to set the delegate for each textfield in order to have this method called for all of them. Therefore you should do `textfield.delegate = self` for each textfield you have